# Make dialogue box with header and label

Tags: java, javafx, joptionpane

How can I make a dialogue box with JOptionPane that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxEob.png)
with a header and description?

Comment: I don't think you can.  You'll need a modal JFrame for something like this.

Comment: Are you sure you're asking about swing's `JOptionPane` And not about JavaFX's `Dialog`/`Alert`?

Comment: @fabian just not sure how to go about it at all, we've only used JOptionPane for dialogue boxes as I'm in a Java 1 course and I figured that was the way the professor did it.

Comment: Are you using the swing api or the javafx api ([`Application` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html) as entry point). I wouldn't recommend using a different GUI framework to display the dialog.

Comment: @fabian I am using the JavaFX api

Comment: @fabian Alright, I figured it out thanks to your mentioning of Dialog/Alert! Learned what I needed from this page http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `Alert` for this purpose instead of `JOptionPane`:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert.setHeaderText("Total: $3.45");

GridPane content = new GridPane();
content.setHgap(10);
content.setVgap(3);
content.addColumn(0, new Text("Order:"), new Text("Tax:"), new Text("Total:"));
content.addColumn(1, new Text("3.25"), new Text("0.20"), new Text("3.45"));

alert.getDialogPane().setContent(content);
alert.showAndWait();
```